# How to convert epsg:28992 to epsg:3857 in python for a shapely polygon

Tags: python, shapely, epsg

The title says it, how do i change the coordinates of an shapely geom from epsg:28992 to epsg: 3857 in python.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78838/converting-projected-coordinates-to-lat-lon-using-python

Comment: but that is for a lat, lon, I want it for a polygon

Comment: how is "polygon" different? polygon is just a bunch of points

Comment: but isnt there a way to do the polygon at once, so i dont have to loop over all the points